# multiple languages and switch between in terminal without rebooting

Tags: centos, terminal, locale

in Linux with GUI, we could add new support languages and switch between, so we could write in new languages and got messages in that.
but, is it possible to do it in terminal(without GUI for example on ssh) and get affected it without the reboot, for example I need add russian and German Language and write with both of them my mail and send.

Comment: I don't understand why someone gave minus reputation

Answer (score 0):

Set your desired presentation language like this:

```
$ LANG=en_UK.UTF-8 app arg1 arg2 ...
```

to change the locale for the duration of only one command.  Do this:

```
$ export LANG=en_UK.UTF-8
$ app arg1 arg2
$ another-app arg1 arg2
```

to set the locale ***in this terminal only***, until the window is closed.

```
$ man locale
```

is your friend.

Comment: it doesn't work.